# JQ to map array to object with index - how to

Tags: json, object, jq, dynamically-generated

pretty simple:

What I have: `'["a","b","c"]'`

What I want:

```json
{
  "1":"a",
  "2":"b",
  "3":"c"
}
```

What I am working with.

```sh
echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq '. | map({(index(.)) : (.)})'
```

What I am getting (it seems to be operating on successively smaller arrays):

```
 echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq '. | map(index((.)))'
[
  0,
  0,
  0
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A functional solution:

```
[to_entries[] | {(.key+1|tostring): .value}] | add
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
with_entries(.key |= (1+.|tostring))
```

Or, more prosaically:

```
. as $in
| reduce range(0;length) as $i (null; 
    . + {($i+1|tostring): $in[$i]})
```

Comment: **Prosaically**: *When you do something prosaically, you do it in an ordinary, straightforward way*. **Succinctly**: *A way that expresses what needs to be said clearly and without unnecessary words*. (For the non-english speakers ;) )